# Who are Merawing.net

Tags: blockchain

Hello I have been contacted by this company saying about your withdrawal process.
As I told you at the moment your funds are in the Blockchain system. With the help of artificial intelligence, we have the option of tracking the transaction that was carried out from your account on the Blockchain system.
Approximate amount of withdrawal 3.6btc
The reservation amount 0.05btc

0.05btc this is a requirement of the Blockchain system. This amount will be frozen inside of the system for a period of two hours approximate. The money can't just disappear. By this step you will activate system for the withdrawal.

The above is from Merawing.net. And would like confirmation that this is a SCAM

Comment: Yes, what you have described is a scam.

Comment: Definitely a scam